# I want to decompress .7z-Files without having 7zip installed

Tags: c#, zip, 7zip, compression

I want to decompress .7z-Files that I'm downloading from a Webserver. I already searched for a Solution but I only found somewhere I have to have 7zip installed.

Is there a simple way to decompress this files?

I already have a "foreach" that loops through items in a list containing the filenames.

Comment: You should only need the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to do this by referencing the correct DLLs in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally had a good experience with the SevenZipSharp library. 
https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Code example for extracting / decompressing:

```
using (var tmp = new SevenZipExtractor(@"d:\Temp\7z465_extra.7z"))
{
       for (int i = 0; i < tmp.ArchiveFileData.Count; i++)
       {
             tmp.ExtractFiles(@"d:\Temp\Result\", tmp.ArchiveFileData[i].Index);
       }
}
```

Just place the needed dll's from 7zip and this library in your programm folder and you're good to go. Therefore, you don't explicitly need 7zip to be installed, you just need the libs.

Comment: If i try to run this Code i get an UnauthizedAccessException. I Already run the Application as Administrator!

Comment: Probably because `d:\Temp\7z465_extra.7z` doesn't exist, the paths are not meant to be representative. Otherwise, check if you have the right path and the right access rights.

Comment: I already edited the Path. I started Visual Studio as Administrator, so the Debugger should also run as Administrator! My Directory i want to use is actually a Directory in my %AppData%-Directory.

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? Try a hardcoded absolute full path. If that doesn't work, maybe something's wrong with the library or its usage. Other than that, it's seperate issue from what's asked in the question.

Comment: The Exception is thrown at this point: `using (var tmp = new SevenZipExtractor(tempdir))` The Code in it is not performed! Tempdir is `string appdata=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); string tempdir = Path.Combine(appdata + "\\D41_Temp");` And i dont know, but maybe the Problem is the Backgroundworker wich performs the Code!

Comment: If you use `Path.Combine()` the second argument must not be prepended with a `\\ `, just give it as the second argument, i.e. use `Path.Combine(appdata, "D41_Temp");`. Does this directory really exist? Maybe you have to create it first with `Directery.CreateDirectory()`.

Comment: Ok, i figured it out. I forgot to give a specific file! Now i ran into another Problem. I implemented the dll as an Resource and i tried to set the Library-Path this way: `SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Resources.SevenZipSharp);` But i cant do it this way!

Comment: I'm afraid if you use `SetLibraryPath()` it wants dll files which are on the disk, not as a stream. You can copy the dll files in your project and set the output type to "Always copy to output dir" or something, then ship your application along with the dlls. Or, there's a method that let's you do that from a stream which I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried the new [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/USAGE.md) and found it great if you don't care about the file type (eg. it can be 7z/zip/rar).

```
using (var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(compressedFile))
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (!entry.IsDirectory)
            entry.WriteToDirectory(@"C:\Temp", new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decompress the .7z file with .Net core 2.2
Download SharpCompress(0.23.0) from nuget.

```
static void SharpCompressEx(string sevenZPath)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(sevenZPath))
        {
            using (var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open(stream))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (!entry.IsDirectory)
                        entry.WriteToDirectory(@"C:\Temp", new ExtractionOptions() { ExtractFullPath = true, Overwrite = true });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but it works extemely slow with password-protected files